# Which humanoid has the highest strength?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I am seeking a humanoid typed creature with as high strength as possible.
The strength may not come from a template, an elite array, or class levels, but solely from its own racial bonuses.

The humanoid must be small, medium or large.

To be specific, it is for the alternate form ability from the Savage Species succubus progression.

I hope to get an answer soon!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Flinds**
Direct from the books, flinds (*MM3* 62) have the highest average Strength scores with 17. *Monster Manual* orcs have Strength scores of 17, but that's due to their arrays. Orcs only *really* get +4 to their Strength scores while flinds get +6.

To win trivia contests, and because sometimes size is more important than raw strength, there's but one Large humanoid, the quinametin (*Dragon* #317 65), but the average quinametin Strength score is only 15, getting them +4 to their Strength score.

While the greensnake shinomen naga (Medium) remained humanoid, the asp (Large), chameleon  (Large), cobra  (Large), and constrictor (Huge) shinomen naga (*OA* 172-5) became monstrous humanoids instead of humanoids in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* with the article "Oriental Adventures: Eastern Flavor" (*Dragon* #318 32-48), therefore excluding your best choices.

Answer (score 4):

Should it ever become relevant, Goliaths and Half Giants (str 15) both have Powerful Build despite being Medium, and are from *Races of Stone* and *Expanded Psionics Handbook* respectively.

Additionally, should survival become a concern, Tren (*Serpent Kingdoms*) are Humanoids with Str 15 and +8 Natural Armour, as well as a Claw/Claw/Bite attack routine and a bonus Multiattack feat.  And a Swim speed.  Crucians, from the slightly more mainstream (*Miniature's Handbook*), also have +8 NA and Str 15 (although, lower dex and no natural attacks).